# Load a text file in a static html page?

Tags: html

I am trying to achieve this: I have a static html page, which needs to load text from a text file, as part of its content. The text file is in the same root folder of the website, which is also where the html page reside.

I am aware that simple html cannot load text from a file; so I am quite clueless about how can I achieve this. The server cannot use dynamic pages (it is quite complex to explain; I am using a web server that I cannot configure; I can just write and run static HTML pages on it).

Is there a trick to read a text file and slap the content on a webpage? Otherwise I am forced to have to create this webpage from scratch every time that the text file changes; using python somehow (I am no expert); which seems like a lot of work.

Comment: You're going to have to script it using JS or jQuery.

Comment: Last time that I touched HTML was 1992...have been writing code in C++ for the past decades; sorry if I don't remember such beginner concepts :) I know Java, so JS shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: <iframe src="mytext.txt"></iframe>

Comment: @newbiez `Java to JavaScript is what Car is to Carpet`. But that should not discourage you to learn new thing.

Comment: Interesting, thanks Subir; altho they share similar syntax (looking at some examples right now), I am aware that a scripting language cannot achieve the same as a fully fledged language. I need just what's enough to achieve my goal, so luckily, I will not have to learn the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot ivarpoiss; just what I was looking for. Could you make it as a reply instead than a comment, so I can vote it? Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Just vote for Abhishek's answer. He should add the iframe option to his post too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do,reading a single txt file everytime or you might want to change the txt file.What you can o is you can use javascript file reader to read the file.
And then you can post the content of the file into the html where ever you want.For a look up,

**your javascript file would look like this,rename it as test.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var textType = /text.*/;

            if (file.type.match(textType)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
                }

                reader.readAsText(file);    
            } else {
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
            }
        });
}
```

**your html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File API</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <h1>Text File Reader</h1>
        <div>
            Select a text file: 
            <input type="file" id="fileInput">
        </div>
        <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>

    </div>

    <script src="text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can mould it to your requirement,like passing the url of your file.I hope this must be what you searching for

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting a text file with results from a server that does calculations on chemical reactions; and the idea was to add these info on a web page. Since they change various time during the day, I would like to avoid to have to update by hand the page all the time; hence the idea to just load the txt file in the web page. I will give a try to your suggestions; thanks!